# Solution for [Cannot update project reference ''] & [Validating Web Site] delay

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Folks,
I have a an old ASP.Net website that I have to modify occasionally.

When I go to build or run the site, I get

> Cannot update project reference ''.
> Source project not
> available.Validating Web Site

It then steps through each folder and page in the project & "Validates" it. The site is quite sizable, and can take 5+ minutes on my beefy Windows-7 PC.

Anyone any ideas how I can track down the '' project reference and get rid of this? The Validation is breaking my heart, small change, run, wait 5 minutes, test, small change, run wait 5 minutes . . . *gag*

ASP.Net isn't my bag so forgive me if this is a school boy error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 stores project references for Web Sites in the Solution file (.sln)

Find and edit or remove the offending project references by editing the Solution file with Notepad or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

#### A typical project entry

(here the GUID {2F769E88-2909-49A8-A5D6-1AF1C27FAB4E} on the far right is the project's ID to be referenced by some other project) ...

```
 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyLibrary", "Source\MyServiceLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj", "{2F769E88-2909-49A8-A5D6-1AF1C27FAB4E}"
 EndProject
```

#### A reference to the above project entry from a Web Site

```
 Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "WebSite", "Source\WebSite", "{66E258DA-36BE-4643-BC7E-2D9D90A6BEB9}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        ...
        ProjectReferences = "{2F769E88-2909-49A8-A5D6-1AF1C27FAB4E}|MyLibrary.dll;"
        ...
    EndProjectSection
 EndProject
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I never though of looking for the website references in the solution file. The problem was indeed in there. Thanks again :)

Comment: NB: this exact message also appears when a properly referenced project is not built due to mismatches in `Configuration|Platform`. Look in Configuration Manager for projects with Build checkbox cleared.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the website in the solution and click 'Property Pages'.  Under references, find the reference which is failing (it will say 'unavailable' next to it), remove and then re-add it.  I believe this solution is preferable to editing the .sln file directly.

Comment: In my case I couldn´t remove the reference in 'Property Pages' window, so I did it editing the .sln file directly.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried switching it off (temporarily) or migrating (if appropriate) to a project instead of a site](http://forums.asp.net/t/939998.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, tried switching it to a web application project, but got - literally - thousands of errors. I tried working through them, but literally got to the point where there were classes included in the project that were'nt being compiled. E.g. Error because `ClassA` does not exist, however `ClassA` exists, but is not compiled, when I put major syntax error into ClassA.cs (i.e. misspell `class`) it isn't reported as an error, bizarre behaviour.

Comment: hmmm... No wonder that the validator has a hard time. Does the site use compile-on-the-fly? I am afraid that i have no other solution than this. Migration to a project might cost a lot but the bennefit could be even more but I can't decide on that

Comment: I hear ya mate. This site has been pieced together over 7 or 8 years by folks - including me - that don't really understand asp.net. I think it's time to start "fixing" it properly, possibly starting another project and moving sections to there, and having the existing project re-direct for those sections. It'll be a hard sell though. Thanks for your feed back.